# Empty insert data to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a file that saves a date input into my database.

Here is my HTML and JS codes:

```
<form id="myForm">
Date:<input type='date' name ='date' required id="date">
<input type="button" name="submits" value="submit" id="btn_submit">
</form>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn_submit").click(function() {
var dates = $("#date").val();

if (dates == '') {
alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
} else {
$.post("datedatabase.php", {
date1: dates
}, function(data) {
alert(data);
$('#myForm')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
});
});
</script>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("date", $connection);
$date2=$_POST['date1']; 

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO date_use (id,dateUSE,stock) VALUES('',$date2,'')"); 
if($query){
echo "Data Submitted succesfully";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed.
?>
```

And when I test it, I saved it to my database and it is successful BUT the data inputted in my database is an empty date like this --> `0000-00-00`. Whats wrong in my code?

Comment: What is the format for the date you post to the db ( $date2)? It looks like it has not a format of yyyy-mm-dd as expected in my Sql. Also note that you should use mysqli or pdo and not mysql. Mysql library in php has been deprecated and removed from php 7 (next release)

Comment: Try this: `INSERT INTO date_use (id,dateUSE,stock) VALUES('',"2015-22-10",'')`, If it is to be saved in the database, then (as @LelioFaieta told, you have *format* problem)

Comment: i found the problem and @LelioFaieta was right. format problem. the input date is mm/dd/yyyy and in database format  is yyyy/mm/dd. how will i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
$date  = $_POST['date1'];
$date2 = strtotime($date);
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', $date2);
```

Comment: The mysql field is not a unix timestamp, this will fail

Comment: wont fail, i guess it will be stored as string. he just have to place it as string, if its a varchar if its date then its fine

Comment: @LelioFaieta: this is what OP said `is an empty date like this --> '0000-00-00'` refers to a time stamp

Comment: Strtotime will take the date stored as a string to a time as a unix timestamp (a number actually) and mysql expect a yyyy-mm-dd string. For your example to work you should convert back the timestamp to a string with the right format

Comment: @LelioFaieta: again as OP mentioned `is an empty date like this --> '0000-00-00'` this refers to classic behavior of time stamp, if you have other solution please provide, other then that i dont think mine is in correct

Comment: This is a mysql date field. Where do you see the timestamp? As per the answer i am waiting to see what the op says he is posting as a date value to give him the right answer

Comment: well i thought the other part is easy i.e converting it to date, but i guess , people dont wanna do all the hard work. i will convert it to date as well, and yes its my mistake i took it for date and time i.e time stamp, but idea was clear on what to do next

Answer (score 0):

To convert the date string from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd you can quickly go this way:

```
list($month, $day,$year)=explode("/", $date2);
$date2 = $year."/".$month."/".$day;
```

This will get your result with just a bit of string manipulation

Or you can go through date conversion to a timestamp as another answer is suggesting.

Comment: Where did you put my code? You have to put it after $date2 has been defined

Comment: i placed it after $date2 = $_POST['date1'];

Comment: this line: list($month, $day,$year)=explode("/", $date2);

Comment: Does mysql allow storing date as string in mysql date field?

Comment: Can you echo $date2 before this line?

Comment: i echo $date2 and it shows 2015-01-01 but why it stores in database an empty date

Comment: can you please edit your question showing the code as you have updated it (including the echo).

Comment: i just found the problem and it is working now. there is no single quotation in VALUES($date2). thanks for your time sir

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry for the typo. Mark the solution if it's working now

Answer (score -1):

Try outputting the string you receive as date2 just before the query and check, the string has the correct format.

Regards